# Display button only when specific child is selected

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xlpagertabstrip

I'm using XLPagerTabStrip in my app to display three different children.. this is working perfectly.

```
  import UIKit
import XLPagerTabStrip

class AccountViewController: ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController {


override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.settings.style.buttonBarBackgroundColor = .white
    self.settings.style.buttonBarItemBackgroundColor = .white
    self.settings.style.selectedBarBackgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.52, green:0.77, blue:0.33, alpha:1.0)
    self.settings.style.buttonBarItemFont = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13)
    self.settings.style.selectedBarHeight = 2.0
    self.settings.style.buttonBarMinimumLineSpacing = 10
    self.settings.style.buttonBarItemTitleColor = .black
    self.settings.style.buttonBarItemsShouldFillAvailableWidth = true
    self.settings.style.buttonBarLeftContentInset = 0
    self.settings.style.buttonBarRightContentInset = 0
    self.settings.style.selectedBarHeight = 4.0

    changeCurrentIndexProgressive = { [weak self] (oldCell: ButtonBarViewCell?, newCell: ButtonBarViewCell?, progressPercentage: CGFloat, changeCurrentIndex: Bool, animated: Bool) -> Void in
        guard changeCurrentIndex == true else { return }
        oldCell?.label.textColor = UIColor(red:0.96, green:0.96, blue:0.96, alpha:1.0)
        newCell?.label.textColor = .black
    }

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let orginalimg = UIImage(named: "Arrow Left")
    let tinitimg = orginalimg?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    backbtn.setImage(tinitimg, for: UIControlState.normal)
    backbtn.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.16, green:0.27, blue:0.60, alpha:1.0)

}

@IBOutlet weak var backbtn: UIButton!
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBOutlet weak var addnewadd: UIButton!
@IBAction func addnewadd(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "addsegue", sender: self)
}

override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] {

    let child1 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "account")
    let child2 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "password")
    let child3 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "address")
    return [child1,child2,child3]
}
}
```

the problem is that I want to show the 'addnewadd' button (which is hidden) when the second tab is selected.

I tried this:

```
   override func updateIndicator(for viewController: PagerTabStripViewController, fromIndex: Int, toIndex: Int, withProgressPercentage progressPercentage: CGFloat, indexWasChanged: Bool) {

    if toIndex == 2 {

        self.addnewadd.isHidden = false

        }
    else{
        self.addnewadd.isHidden = true
    }
   }
```

this works but the tab won't change when swiped to another child it will always stay selected on the first tab ...

how can I solve this?

Comment: The tab won't change when you swipe it right - left but clicking on tab works, am I right?

Comment: @StepanValchyshyn yes right .. do you have an idea how to solve it?

Comment: first of all check if your scroll is enabled for containerView. Or write containerView.isScrollEnabled = false inside viewDidLoad()

Comment: @StepanValchyshyn i got this: Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'isScrollEnabled'

Comment: did you mistake containerView with something else? If you did everything right, your containerView should be of type UIScrollView. Check again your view hierarchy. containerView is the view that stores your child controllers.

Comment: @StepanValchyshyn ok just tried it.. this will make me not able to swipe between the childern.. when i want .. the only problem is changing the current selected item in the tab